# Repeated values should not show together in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to display some data and my requirement is repeated values should not be shown adjacent.
Right now the data in the table is in this order

```
ID     Name
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   C
5   B
6   B
7   C
8   C
9   C
```

Expected result - It should be in below order

```
ID   Name
1   A
3   B
4   C
2   A
5   B
7   C
6   B
8   C
9   C
```

Comment: look at last two values in expected result... these are adjacent C's. Is there a better way to phrase the logic 'repeated values should not be shown adjacent'.

Comment: Last two values are left overs which has to displayed in the result if there are no other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS rn
FROM mytable
ORDER BY rn, Name
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d258a418a70c9fd5daf544dfe4c045b)

Answer (score 1):

You can put `row_number()` directly in the `order by`.  I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by name order by id),
         name;
```